# Safari does not work after Big Sur upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, big-sur

So I just installed Big Sur, and my Safari is completely offline. Turning the bluetooth off made it connect for a few minutes. I am having to use other browsers, which works fine.
Also, my app store is completely dark and unresponsive.

Anyone had/have the same issue?

Comment: Have you tried booting in safe-mode and reset SMC/NVRAM? Also, can you try a wired connection over LAN?

Comment: @X_841 reset smc and nvram I did. Also safe mode. Will try a wired connection see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone runs into the same issue, here were the steps I performed to solve the issue.

On system report, under applications, I identified all 32 bit applications and deleted them.
That gave me back safari for a session (stopped working after restart), but still overall icloud and mail wouldnt connect.

After restart I disabled wifi, created a new network location, and set the DNS to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 and renew my dhcp lease. And under the hardware set a custom MTU to 1492.

System started working again faster than ever. I logged in back to icloud and restarted.

After that, all was working, App Store connecting and updating apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [XCode 12](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) and check if that help you to fix the issue.

It helps to fix many crashing issues of Safari after upgrading to Big Sur.

I am not sure but Safari might depend upon XCode command line too.

Comment: Thanks! That’s another issue. App Store is just dark! It shows an update available badge, but its completely empty... I did install the xcode dev tools, using command line, but noy sure how to install xcode 12 through the command line

Comment: have you tried it: sudo xcode-select --install from terminal.

Comment: i did, but it only install comanda line tolls

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcaHZDdmk8k&ab_channel=Humphirion - Reset Key Chain and it helps to fix AppStore. If you haven't done it yet, then I would recommend.

Comment: That solved the apple store issue, thanks

Comment: I upgrade XCODE 12, but didnt work.... actually, now my app store is gone again (after restarting)

Answer (score 0):

No. The issues you speak of are not related to installing Big Sur.  Something else is needed to impact Safari and the App Store conn3cting to resources outside your mac.

Networking, dns and firewall software are the things that typically impact multiple apps, but the best strategy might be to pick one app and one target and isolate / troubleshoot that and then repeat with the next app or the next online service.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the proxies. Check out this video https://youtu.be/wlA2pmM5c6k for a solution to fix the problem. I had the same issue, App Store blacking out on me and Safari not accessing websites (even though other browsers could) following my upgrade to Big Sur. I followed the steps in the link above, and it worked! I hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).